# Android studio remove debug tag from files to included in release

Tags: android, android-studio

To increase the productivity, I've created another `string.xml` file and named as `string_map.xml`. I've noticed that if the file is created when build variant is debug it has debug tag

`string_map.xml (debug)`

and not included in release tag and and similarly for the other case.

How one can remove the tag on the file so that it can be used both for debug and release?

- Studio version 3.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same file(s) to be used in both debug and release variants, just place it under the `main` folder. Note that if you create a debug-specific file your release version won't be shipping that debug file.

Example:

```
app/src -- main        
         |   |
         |   -- res
         |       |
         |       -- values
         |             |
         |             -- strings.xml
         |- debug
              |
              -- res
                  |
                  -- values
                       |
                       -- strings.xml
```

As long as the files across all variants have the exact same name, Android will know how to figure out which one to use and again, the debug variant will only ship with the debug file, the release variant will only ship with the main file and so on.

Comment: Your solution requires a non Studio solution. Studio  doesn't ask me it is main or debug.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not following it.

Comment: If the build variant is debug the xml file created with debug tag, if the build variant is main it is created with release tag. How can I force it to main without using explorer?

Comment: Just check your project's directory structure in Android Studio and see where that file in question is placed. If you want it to be the same regardless of build variant it should be in the main folder. And if you don't want that file to be "polymorphic" then you need to make sure there aren't any other files with the same name anywhere else in your project

Comment: Your solution is ok if I want to play with the folders. My point is the studio decides the tag not me.

Comment: Show me a screenshot so I can see exactly what you're on about. From what you're telling me seems like the only way to get through this is through folder management, not Android Studio specifically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192002/discussion-between-alanc92-and-kelalaka).

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in Android Studio, right click on the file:
`Refactor -> Move File` or `click F6` on your keyboard. If you want to copy it instead of moving it, `click F5` on your keyboard.

[image: Menu sub-options]

Then, click the drop-down and click the top option to move it to the "main" folder instead of the "debug" folder

[image]